# Create an exposed filter block from a BLOCK display output

Tags: blocks, views

I'm trying to show my views exposed filter as a block (so it's placeable in the block structure), from a block display. I understand if I was using a page display, I could just use "Advanced > Exposed Form" to show as block, but the option doesn't exist if the views' output is a block.

I've search everywhere, and I can't find any solution. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 9):

In Drupal 7+ ensure that in the "advanced settings->other" in your block view, Use ajax=YES.

Comment: Awesome! it just works. Great!

Answer (score 3):

You can make this happen by following these steps:

1. Create a view with a page display (e.g. myview)
2. In Advanced settings, change the machine name of the display page (e.g. mypagedisplay)
3. Choose "Exposed filter in block"
4. Enable the PHP filter
5. Create a block, and embed this code:

   ```
   <?php
     print views_embed_view("my view", "mypagedisplay");
   ?>
   ```
6. Choose the PHP input format for the block

Comment: I can confirm this works, thanks you!!! I recommend using a small custom module for the block instead of a block with the php filter which is evil.

Answer (score 3):

There is also now a module [views block filter block](https://drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block), that overrides the block views display type to allow having a block view with exposed filters in a block.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 8 the only way I could get this work was to have a Page view where I have selected "Expose filters as block" Then On the content type that I want to have the view as a block I use https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference and set it as a field I can then have the Page view in this reference field and have my exposed filters block in the sidebar of the page. 
This might not work for everyone's use case but hopefully helps some people :)